# Microphone Audio Visualizer Web Audio API

Tags: html, audio, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I am new in Canvas of HTML5. What I want to do. I want a microphone audio visualizer just like windows Sound visualizer of microphone (control panel => hardware and sound => Sound => recording)
Can anybody tell me Please how I will create it in canvas and adjust with web audio API ?
An other problem is My visualizer is more sensitive. How i will adjust it. I want blank spectrum if no sound is there.
I am sharing a picture what I exactly want. 
Img url: http://phillihp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/winamp-step-pre-step-1.png
Please help me out to solve this problem.
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

```
<body>
<canvas id="test"></canvas>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio:true}, function(stream){
audioContext = new AudioContext();
analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
microphone = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
javascriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);

analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.0;
analyser.fftSize = 512;

microphone.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
javascriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

//canvasContext = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
canvasContext = document.getElementById("test");
canvasContext= canvasContext.getContext("2d");

javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
var values = 0;

var length = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
values += array[i];
}

var average = values / length;
canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 300);
canvasContext.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
canvasContext.fillRect(0,130-average,25,140);
}

}, function(e){ console.log(e); }
                        );
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need to analyse frequencies just to know the sound level. Just hook the microphone directly to the processor node.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code sample: https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter/.

Comment: works on PC (Windows/FFox/Chrome) but not on Android (Chrome). the green volume bar simply does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on cwilso answer. Fixed the problem with mobile devices. "StartNow" is the main JS function in main.js (originallt called by window.onload):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Volume Meter</title>
        <script src="volume-meter.js"></script>     
        <script src="main.js"></script>     
    </head>

    <body onload="javascript:StartNow()"> >
        <p>uses audioContext.createScriptProcessor(buffer size) Web Audio API. Use https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#audioworklet</p>
        <canvas id="meter" width="1100" height="60"></canvas>

        <p>On Android press button to start (fixes new security requirement added in the new Android OS version)</p>
        <button onclick="javascript:StartNow()">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

On Android you need to press the button to start.
This is necessary because of a NEW security requirement added in the new Android OS.